# JavaMail BaseEncode64 Error

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, multipart

I'm currently developing an application which download attachment from gmail account.
Right now, I got error whenever downloading zipped attachment. But, not all, some I can retrieve it without error. Here's the Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed 4 valid base64 characters but only got 1 before EOF, the 10 most recent characters were: "Q3w5ilxj2P"
```

FYI: I was able to download the attachment via gmail web interface.

Here's the snippet:

```
        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {

            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

            if (bodyPart.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith("zip") ||
                    bodyPart.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith("rar")) {
                InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                File f = new File("/tmp/" + bodyPart.getFileName());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                byte[] buf = new byte[bodyPart.getSize()];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone have idea, how to work around this problem?

Comment: nope, not yet. Seems like. no one is interested in java mail:(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a list of the [known limitations, bugs, issues](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/notes12-150225.txt) of JavaMail:

> Certain IMAP servers do not implement
>   the IMAP Partial FETCH  functionality
>   properly. This problem typically
>   manifests as corrupt email attachments
>   when downloading large messages from
>   the IMAP  server. To workaround this
>   server bug, set the 
>     "mail.imap.partialfetch"  property to
>   false. You'll have to set this
>   property in the Properties object that
>   you provide to your Session.

So you should just **turn off** partial fetch in imap session. For example:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>","<password>");
```

source: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html

Comment: What if that doesn't fix it? I have set `properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");` (I've also tried setting "mail.imap.partialfetch", which didn't help either), yet I still get an exception of the kind "BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed 4 valid base64 characters but only got 1 before EOF"

Answer (score 1):

If You Are Using java mail API then add these lines while you are connectin the imap server......

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch", false);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
```

........
.... your code ..
......

it should work.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) the property values must always be set as string. It seems that you used a boolean value that probably won't have any effect.