# Downloading a word Document from Gmail using Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using Javamail API, and I'm trying to download an attachment file, for example a word file. 
The problem is I get a base64 decoding exception while trying to read the bytes and save it to a file.
I'm using the following code for that purpose.

Stack Exception:

```
IOException:com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed 4 valid base64 characters but only got 2 before EOF, the 10 most recent characters were: "AG4AAAAAAA"
```

JavaMail Code:

```
 private void getAttachments(Message temp) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        List<File> attachments = new ArrayList<File>();

        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) temp.getContent();

        System.out.println(multipart.getCount());

        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {
                continue; // dealing with attachments only
            }
            InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();


            File f = new File("C:\\Attachments\\" + bodyPart.getFileName());

          //  saveFile(bodyPart.getFileName(),is);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while (br.ready()) {
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }



           saveFile(bodyPart.getFileName(),is);

            attachments.add(f);
        }



public static void saveFile(String filename,InputStream input) 
    {

        System.out.println(filename);
        try {
            if (filename == null) {
                //filename = File.createTempFile("VSX", ".out").getName();
                return;
            }
            // Do no overwrite existing file
            filename = "C:\\Attachments\\" + filename;
            File file = new File(filename);
            for (int i = 0; file.exists(); i++) {
                file = new File(filename + i);
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);


            int aByte;
            while ((aByte = bis.read()) >=0) {
                bos.write(aByte);
            }

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            bis.close();
        } // end of try()
        catch (IOException exp) {
            System.out.println("IOException:" + exp);
        }
    } //end of saveFile()
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. So probably your problem lies in the JavaMail-specific code. Can you show us that code, together with the message and stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @RolandIllig
I've edited the code again

Comment: What happens when you us the saveFile() method from the MimeBodyPart directly instead of rolling your own save logic?

Comment: It has been solved: 
The problem is you have to set the properties of the IMAP as partial fetch. 

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable partial fetch to get rid of this issue. Here is how you can do that

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
```

or

```
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
```

if you are working using imaps.

Here is the full reference:
[JavaMail BaseEncode64 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755414/javamail-baseencode64-error)

Comment: What if that doesn't fix it? I have set properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false"); (I've also tried setting "mail.imap.partialfetch", which didn't help either), yet I still get an exception of the kind "BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed 4 valid base64 characters but only got 1 before EOF"

Comment: Can you please share your code base and error details.

Comment: Disregard my comment, it was just actually an email with malformed BASE64 content! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the saveFile() method from MimeBodyPart. And if you really want to role your own stop(!) reading lines from the inputstream before handing it over to your saveFile method. Your are consuming part of the content, which may contribute to the problem.